Backyard erosion
Our home (and entire neighborhood) was built in 2015. We are the first owners. (As an aside, also first-time homeowners). Since day 1 we have had erosion issues with our backyard. The ground was not properly compacted during construction and according to the essayer, we have a rill. Essentially our backyard is falling away. We've had two projects fix the holes under the corners of our backyard fence, but the problem is getting worse and I think we'll eventually need to do a complete backyard overhaul. Who is the right first call for such a project?

Landscaping company

Have you determined what is causing the rill?  Do you have a concentrated flow (gutter downspout or something)?  Can it be diverted to a less steep area?  Some pics would sure help us help you...
